# SAPUI5 OPA Test - Message box - Error

Tags: testing, button, sapui5, messagebox

I am facing issues while pressing different buttons on message-boxes on JavaScript views of my SAPUI5 application. Other item seems to work fine like inserting text in text boxes, pressing buttons, selecting a row of table, etc.

I found out that every messagebox has a type/class like `sapMDialogSuccess` or `sapMDialogError` or `sapMDialogWarning`, etc. Do we have a similar type/class for `OK`, `Cancel`, `Abort` buttons (displayed on `MessageBox`)?

I am able to get exact text which appears on my `MessageBox` using:

```
ok(true, "This success message is displayed:- " +
sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".sapMDialogSuccess").
find(".sapMText").text());
```

But when I try following code to select (and then press) OK button, it does not work. Here is the code I am using:

```
//OK Button - Find & Press OK button 
Then.waitFor({
    pollingInterval: 5,
    searchOpenDialogs: true,
    controlType: "sap.m.Button",

    check: function(aButton) {
        if (aButton.text() === "OK") {
            return !!sap.ui.test.Opa5.getJQuery()(".sapMDialogSuccess").length;
        }
    },
    success: function() {
        ok(true, "OK button found - SUCCESS");
    },
    errorMessage: "OK Button not found - ERROR"
});
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
OK Button not found - ERROR
Callstack:
    at Object.<anonymous> (http: //<<server>>:50000/XMII/CM/Opa-LineGroupMaintenance.html:152:22)
    at Object.f (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/test/opaQunit.js:6:331)
    at Object.run (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:9294)
    at eval (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:11222)
    at C (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:5918)
    at E (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:6299)
    at eval (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:6431)@ 3618 ms
Expected:   
true
Result:     
false
Diff:   
trufalse
Source:     
    at Object.eval [as ok] (https:// sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/qunit.js:11:20688)
Script error.@ 3623 ms
Source:     
:0
```

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me in this way. the Success Function we have to do `firePress()` event:

```
Then.onTheTranslationPage.ipressOKButton();

ipressOKButton: function () {
    var oOrderNowButton = null;
    return this.waitFor({
        viewName: sViewName,
        searchOpenDialogs: true, //mandatory
        controlType: "sap.m.Button", //optional
        success: function (aButtons) {
            return aButtons.filter(function (oButton) {
                if(oButton.getText() == "OK") {
                    oOrderNowButton = oButton;
                    oButton.firePress();
                }
            });

            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Form Got Submitted Successfully");
        },
        actions: new Press(),
        errorMessage: "Did not find the dialog control"
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I found following piece of code working for me:

```
                Then.waitFor({
                    pollingInterval: 10, //optional
                    searchOpenDialogs: true, //mandatory
                    //controlType: "sap.m.Button", //optional
                    success: function(oDialogs) {
                        if (oDialogs[oDialogs.length - 1].$().text() === "OK") {
                            oDialogs[oDialogs.length - 1].$().trigger("click");
                            Opa5.assert.ok(true, "Found OK button inside open dialog!");
                        }
                    },
                    errorMessage: "Did not find either the open dialog or buttons inside an open dialog"
                });
```